Blazor.web.js in .NET 8 deprecated
I'm considering building a website with Blazor, and SEO is very important for me. I have tried all the Blazor WebApp variants, but PageSpeed Insights consistently flags blazor.web.js as deprecated. For SEO purposes, only the Interactive Mode Server is relevant.
How can this be prevented? As it stands, I cannot use Blazor because of this issue.
What plans does Microsoft have for the future regarding this? The unload event is quite important for Blazor.
Is Blazor already becoming outdated?
Thank you in advance for your help!
I have tested Blazor Server, Blazor WebAssembly, and Blazor Hybrid.
All of these configurations resulted in PageSpeed Insights flagging blazor.web.js as deprecated.
